# How to convert field in opencsv correct?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have csv file with this columns id,equity_name,field,date,quartal,year. I have java class where there is a field

```
   @Column(
            columnDefinition = "smallint"
    )
    @Convert(
            converter = YearAttributeConverter.class
    )
    @CsvCustomBindByName(column = "year", converter = YearCsvConverter.class)
    private Year year;
```

And i use custom converter for this field.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class YearCsvConverter extends AbstractBeanField {
    @Override
    protected Object convert(String value) throws CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvConstraintViolationException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);
    }
}
```

When i tried to parse file i have an

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-6" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException: Conversion of 1990-12-31 to java.time.LocalDate failed.
```

How to make this work and convert the field?

Answer (score 0):

Your converter returns a `LocalDate`, but your field is of type `Year`, that is your `DataTypeMismatch` in the `CsvDataTypeMismatchException`.
Make your converter return an object of the correct data type e.g.:

```
return Year.fromLocalDate(LocalDate.parse(value, formatter));
```

On a side note: if you `csvBindByName` or `CsvCustomBindByName`, you don't need to specify the column name, and the following should work as long as your field name matches your header name.

```
@CsvCustomBindByName(converter = YearCsvConverter.class)
private Year year;
```